# my forEach function is not working

Tags: javascript

This javascript code is supposed to accept a string and returns the number of vowels in the array, but when I run it, i get a message that my s.split is not a function. Anybody know what I am doing wrong?

```
function countVowels(s){
    var vowels = /[aeiou]/i;
    var count = 0
    var array = s.split('');

    array.forEach(function(v){
        if(v == vowels)
            count++;
    })
    return count;   
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you call your `countVowels` function?

Comment: Your error would occur when the value of `s` that is passed to your function is not a string.  Your function also doesn't work because `v == vowels` does not do a regex match.  It compares to see if `v` is that actual regex object which it never can be so will that check will always be false.

Comment: That is not how you use a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

> I get a message that my s.split is not a function.

See [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> The `split()` method splits a **String** object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.

So if the param isn't a string type (like 'abcdef'), it'll get you this problem.

And you don't should not use `v === vowels` when `vowels` is a regex. When you use `===`, you are trying to compare whether `v` and `vowels` are same object or not. See [Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) for more details.

See [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

> Use `test()` whenever you want to know whether a pattern is found in a string.

```js
function countVowels(s) {
    var vowels = /[aeiou]/i;
    var count = 0;
    var array = s.split('');

    array.forEach(function(v) {
        if (vowels.test(v)) {
            count++;
        }
    });

    return count;
}

console.log(countVowels('abcdefg'));
```

Comment: Note, the OP refers to an error message about `s.split` not being a function.  Your answer does not address that issue which if it occurs in teh OP's code would still be an issue in your code.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thx. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Foremost: `s` needs to be a string, or `s.split` won't exist.

Also, as others have stated, your test won't work because `v == vowels` will try to equate a string to a regular expression. You'd want to use the [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method:

```
if(vowels.test(v)) { ... }
```

Lastly, there's a cleaner way to count vowels in your string. You can use [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to return all of the matches and use the length of that array:

```
function countVowels(str) {
  return str.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length;
}
```